# How may I obtaining value of label element using substring in label's for attribute using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to obtain the value of label elements using jQuery (or javascript). The only search term I have is a substring of the label element's for attribute. In the example code shown below, this would be 'Okuku'.

```
<label class="required" for="Nigeria-Osun-Okuku">The Township of Okuku</label>
```

The Script:

```
$("label[for='Nigeria-Osun-Okuku']").text();
```

would return

> The Township of Okuku

but I don't have the complete 'for' value: Nigeria-Osun-Okuku **but the last substring of it: 'Okuku'**.

How can I script to search, match and ***return: The Township of Okuku*** ? Thanks

Comment: its working just fine http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/99/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`attribute-contains`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector:

```
$("label[for*='Okuku']").text();
```

Note, this will grab all elements that match that substring.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sYdN4/

If you are *sure* that this substring is found at the end of the value, you could use the ends-with selector:

```
$("label[for$='Okuku']").text();
```

Which will return elements whose `for` attribute *ends with* the substring.

Comment: You must have broken a speed record right there. Answered correctly in less than 30 seconds after submitting. Brilliant. Thanks.

Comment: Along with a jsfiddle link. Your clock must be running slow ;) +1

Comment: @Jashwant: Clock in question hand crafted by Company called Hyperbole (heard of that?)

Answer (score 1):

Use attribute contains selector [*=](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$("label[for*='Okuku']").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to line

**but the last substring of it: 'Okuku'**

```
$("label[for$='Okuku']").text();
```

**[Sample workout](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/100/)**

Read about [**$=**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector.